# Spring Integration: How to get value from util:map into SI's Router

Tags: spring, spring-integration

My configuration is like below:

I am using SpEL inside router to get values from map.

```
    <util:map id="routeConfig">
        <entry key="Default" value="not configured" />
        <entry key="GB22XXX" value="LON" />       
        <entry key="AEADXXX" value="ME" />
        <entry key="HBXXXX" value="ME" />
        <entry key="EBHBXBAO" value="ME" />
</util:map>

<router input-channel="InputRoutingChannel" default-output-channel="testOutputChannel"  expression="@routeConfig.get('payload.getMsgHeader().getSourceSystem().substring(4, 12)')">
        <mapping value="LON" channel="MarshallerOutputChannel_lonme" />
        <mapping value="ME" channel="MarshallerOutputChannel_me" />
</router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
expression="@routeConfig.get('payload.getMsgHeader().getSourceSystem().substring(4, 12)')
```

Since you get deal with runtime `Message` you really don't need to wrap to the `literal`. Hence an answer to you is:

```
expression="@routeConfig.get(payload.msgHeader.sourceSystem.substring(4, 12))
```

Comment: Now I'm getting below error:
**EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'ERROR' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage'
STACKTRACE : org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:216)
org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)**

Comment: Share, please, the whole StackTrace as an edit to your question. Seems for me it isn't related to that `router` config

Comment: that was my bad, pls ignore. SPEL expression is always returning **null** if I use: **expression="@routeConfig.get(payload.msgHeader.sourceSystem.substring(4, 12))**

Comment: OK. So, be sure that `payload.getMsgHeader().getSourceSystem().substring(4, 12)` doesn't return `null`

Comment: **expression="@businessConfigReader.getGMGRouteForEntity(@routeConfig.get(payload.msgHeader.sourceSystem.substring(4, 12)))"
<beans:bean id="businessConfigReader"  class="com.xxx.BusinessConfigReader" />** Can you suggest what's wrong with above expression.

Comment: LGTM. Try to achieve correct SpEL starting from the Java code.